# Toggle animation is not working well

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working in an ionic project, and I'm trying to do this:
When I click the sync button, the button has to disappear and in it's place needs to appear a loading animation for 1200ms.
I tried to use ng-show or ng-hide but is not working.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Html:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
                <button ng-hide={{loading}} class="button button-icon button-clear ion-loop" ng-click="sync()"></button>
                <div ng-hide={{!loading}}>
                    <ion-spinner icon="spiral" class="spinner-assertive"></ion-spinner>
                </div>
                <h1 class="title" style="text-align:center;">Chamados</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.sync = function(){
$http.get(ip+'/tarefas/'+window.localStorage.getItem("user")).success(function(data) {
  $scope.loading = false;
  setTimeout(function () {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.loading = true;
      });
  }, 1200);
  $scope.task = angular.fromJson(data);
});
}
```

Comment: I find out the problem

Comment: if you have found the solution please post an answer. I am also having same problem

Comment: btw, other than spinner which is obvious, I cant see any animation code above (as written in heading)